# localtime() and gmtime() giving exactly the same output

Tags: c

**ADDENDUM:**
I followed [the suggestion provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72135868/5651468) and replaced calls to `gmtime` and `localtime` with calls to `gmtime_r` and `localtime_r` and everything worked as expected.  The updated source code is as follows:

```
int main()
{
    time_t tmi;
    time(&tmi);
    struct tm utcTime, localTime;
    gmtime_r(&tmi, &utcTime);
    localtime_r(&tmi, &localTime);
    
    displayStructTm(&utcTime, "UTC");
    displayStructTm(&localTime, "Local Time");

    return (0);
}
```

---

**Original Post:**

I am making calls to `gmtime()` and `localtime()`, passing the same `time_t` value to both.  However, I am getting the same result.
Here is my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void displayStructTm(const struct tm* tmPtr, const char*label) {
    printf("\n%s\n", label);
    printf("tm_sec: %d\n", tmPtr->tm_sec);
    printf("tm_hour: %d\n", tmPtr->tm_hour);
    printf("tm_min: %d\n", tmPtr->tm_min);
    printf("tm_mday: %d\n", tmPtr->tm_mday);
    printf("tm_mon: %d\n", tmPtr->tm_mon);
    printf("tm_year: %d\n", tmPtr->tm_year);
    printf("tm_wday: %d\n", tmPtr->tm_wday);
    printf("tm_yday: %d\n", tmPtr->tm_yday);
    printf("tm_isdst: %d\n", tmPtr->tm_isdst);
}

int main()
{
    time_t tmi;
    time(&tmi);
    struct tm* utcTime = gmtime(&tmi);
    struct tm* localTime = localtime(&tmi);
    
    displayStructTm(utcTime, "UTC");
    displayStructTm(localTime, "Local Time");

    return (0);
}
```

The output is as follows.  **As can be seen, we get the same output in both cases.**

```
UTC
tm_sec: 27
tm_hour: 3
tm_min: 21
tm_mday: 6
tm_mon: 4
tm_year: 122
tm_wday: 5
tm_yday: 125
tm_isdst: 0

Local Time
tm_sec: 27
tm_hour: 3
tm_min: 21
tm_mday: 6
tm_mon: 4
tm_year: 122
tm_wday: 5
tm_yday: 125
tm_isdst: 0
```

---

Comment: What is the local time zone of the machine?

Comment: Check if `utcTime` and `localTime` point at the same memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The return value points to a statically-allocated struct which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and time functions. The `localtime_r()` function does the same, but stores the data in a user-supplied struct.

— [man localtime](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime)

Since you call `gmtime`, then call `localtime`, before printing either, you're getting two pointers to the same struct, which only contains the second result. Either print each result immediately after the call, or use `localtime_r` and `gmtime_r` with pointers to `struct tm`s that you have allocated yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities.

1. The local time zone of your system currently has an offset of 0.
2. `utcTime` and `localTime` are sharing the same memory.

`localtime` and `gmtime` return a pointer to the same struct every time. They may share the same memory. So `utcTime` and `localTime` might be the same.

You can check with `printf("gm: %p local: %p", utcTime, localTime)`.

Use `localtime_r` and `gmtime_r` to avoid this.